# Simplifying expressions with directional derivative

Tags: simplifying-expressions

Suppose I have a function $f(x, y)$ which is differentiable everywhere (but not explicit). When I run a code snippet like:

```
FullSimplify[Limit[ (f[x + h, y] - f[x, y])/h , h -> 0]]
```

I get the same limit. Is there a way to introduce some assumption such that the output of the above is something like

```
f'[x, y].{1, 0}
```

Or similar?

Comment: Mathematica does not do anything with `Limit[(f[x+h]-f[x])/h,h->0]` if $f(x)$ is not already defined. i.e. it does not give `f'[x]`. But if you have it defined, say `f[x_]:=x^2` then it will now give $2 x$. So for your case, you need to have `f[x,y]` defined before for the limit to do something.

Comment: @Nasser Seems to be doable. See below

Comment: This option is not documented anywhere.  If you look help page for Limit, it does not mention it.  Also doing `?Analytic`  it says `Analytic is an option for Limit and Series.` but clicking on the link for help gives not found page error. But I am glad it is something that works for you, I never seen this option before myself. Too many options, too little time.

Comment: @Nasser: This option is documented: see Properties & Relations [in the documentation to `Limit`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Limit.html?q=Limit).

Comment: @user64494 I see it there. I was looking at options (13) and did not see it there. Makes it hard to find otherwise. But good option to know about.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Analytic->True` option does the job:

```
Limit[(f[x + h, y] - f[x, y])/h, h -> 0, Analytic -> True]
```

> `(f^(1,0))[x,y]`

Comment: Moreover,`Limit[(f[x + h, y + k*h] - f[x, y])/h, h -> 0, Analytic -> True]` results in $$k f^{(0,1)}(x,y)+f^{(1,0)}(x,y) .$$

Comment: Wow, this is really slick. Thanks!

Comment: Pleasure is mine.